# reCaptcha on partial view Laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel-4, google-api, recaptcha

I am trying to implement reCaptcha on my old Laravel application. It is in Laravel4. I am trying with this [bundle](https://github.com/jasonlewis/laravel-recaptcha).
The problem is that **the captcha is not rendering to the when I am calling it on the partial view**.
Is there any quick solution? Help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

That bundle specifies that it is for the server side validation only.  It doesn't offer anything to render the recaptcha, so you still need to follow Google's code for rendering to the client.  What code are you using to render to the client?

The original question stated Laravel 3.  If you are actually on Laravel 4 as the edit states, I would suggest using the [greggilbert/recaptcha](https://github.com/greggilbert/recaptcha) package, as it offers both the server side validation and the client side rendering.

Comment: It says so, but we can call the markup from there like `Recaptcha::recaptcha_get_html('public_key')`. Its working fine but not in partial blade template

Comment: Gotcha. Yeah, looking into the actual library, it looks like that should work.  Are you qualifying it with the namespace?  I assume your partial should have something like this in it: `{{ Recaptcha\Recaptcha::recaptcha_get_html($public_key) }}`.  Can you show an example of where it worked and where it didn't?

Comment: I tried with my contact page like this `{{ Recaptcha\Recaptcha::recaptcha_get_html($public_key) }}` Its working perfectly. When I am trying to add in my product page, there a partial view like,`getcontact.blade.php` its showing nothis. In HTML source there is only a <noscript> content :(, any guess?

Comment: Does your partial view have access to the $public_key variable?  Does {{ $public_key }} print out the right data?  Does {{{ Recaptcha\Recaptcha::recaptcha_get_html($public_key) }}} print out the script and noscript stuff to the page (note the three brackets vs two)?